# no OEM certificate found in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bios, uefi, windows-activation, oem

i want to clean install win 8 on my new lenovo, i have heard that OEM key is stored in the bios and is automatically applied on a clean install. so i decided to save the OEM CERTIFICATE using a software called SLIC TOLKIT 3.2. but it shows that, SLIC STATUS = INVALIDATED, and an error - "No OEM Certificate found".

i have downloaded windows 8 ISO file from internet- en_windows_8_x64_dvd_915440.iso . should i proceed with a clean install, or i have to install an OEM CERTIFICATE ? in control panel- system, it shows windows is activated.

i am also not able to use windows 8 recovery features, like refresh or reset. all these errors started when i created a third partition in windows. then i repaired the boot menu through bios by using - bcdboot c:\windows /s g: /f UEFI . can i clean install windows 8?

Comment: Did your computer come with Windows 8?

Comment: Windows 8 has the ability to Reset your installation I would use that feature if I were you

Comment: My laptop came with windows 8

Comment: Did you check for a label on the bottom of the laptop?

Comment: there is no label with a product key on the bottom of the laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked the same on Technet and the answer is the same. Windows 8 no longer uses OEM certificates with generic OEM keys. Your individual OEM key is embedded to the UEFI on OEM PCs. Windows 8 Setup will pick the key if you don't force the setup to use a different key:

> When installing Windows 8 and Window Server 2012, setup.exe uses the
>   following priority logic for product keys:
>
> 1. Answer file (Unattended file, EI.cfg, or PID.txt)
> 2. OA 3.0 product key in the BIOS/Firmware
> 3. Product key entry screen

Answer (score 1):

From the filename, my *guess* is that this is an illegal ISO image. You won't want to use that. Apart from being illegal, you have no certainty that it is valid and not, say, infected or missing important pieces. Also, your product key may not work with this.

Lenovo does indeed embed the product key in the BIOS, according to [this post](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/Reinstall-Windows-8/td-p/968251). You can find instructions on performing a clean install of Windows 8 on a Thinkpad or a Lenovo B, E, K, M, and V series notebook at [this link](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/Reinstall-Windows-8/td-p/968251). You can create Recovery Media using [these instructions](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=HT076024), though if you have already reformatted your system, it is too late; you'll need to contact Lenovo and see if they can send you recovery media.

If you are upgrading your computer from Windows 7, you will need to purchase an appropriate license which will come with a product key and installation media.

Comment: i think this is a legal iso file as i have downloaded it from microsoft website, and this is the same version of windows 8 which came with my laptop.

Comment: `From the filename, my guess is that this is an illegal ISO image.`   Nah, it’s [probably fine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/hh442898.aspx#FileId=50110). It’s good to check the hash though.