# Restoring Windows 10 Image on Original hardware with Retail licensing

Tags: windows-10, restore, license, system-restore

I bought a 'mini-PC' with Windows 10 Pro(which I can link if necessary) and I want to be able to do 'clean reinstalls' if something gets mucked up.  I pulled the licenses for Windows and Office for safe keeping and created a system image.  I was going to test the Image restore but remembered the product listing it as a 'retail' license that 'would not work if it was removed and reinstalled on the computer.'

Will I be able to reimage this computer an unlimited number of times on the same set of hardware, not transferring to another box or changing hardware?

Comment: OEM devices have Windows key embedded into the UEFI since Windows 8 and Windows [setup will pick it during clean install](https://superuser.com/a/655297/174557)

Comment: Retail licensing (at least traditionally) can be reinstalled and even moved from PC to PC, provided that only one PC has it at any given time.  it is OEM licensing that is traditionally limited to the PC upon which it was purchased, and can only be reinstalled via the options provided by the OEM of note.

Comment: Alright, testing time them.  Begin the image restore!

Comment: Total success, thanks for confirming, if someone wants to make answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I transfer a Windows 10 licence to my new PC if it was upgraded from a retail licence?](https://superuser.com/questions/980204/can-i-transfer-a-windows-10-licence-to-my-new-pc-if-it-was-upgraded-from-a-retai)

Comment: @Ramhound Although the answer there may contain the correct info, I am not concerned with "transferring" the license as the title states, just with restoring an image to the unchanged, originally licensed hardware, also, I would not have found that cus they spelled license wrong lol

Comment: It was the closest question I could find in the amount of time I dedicated to that task.  Your question has been answered before.  Better duplicate candidate: https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit-and-source-a

Comment: @Ramhound I looked and found some for Win8 but nothing up to date on 10 or I wouldn't have asked

Comment: @Cand3r - The Windows retail licensing has not changed.  The only difference is the fact Windows 10 has a digital entitlement, so the work you spent retrieving your key, wasn't necessary.  If you were willing to accept Frank's comment as an answer, then the potential duplicates, should also be potential answers (except they are actually answers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit-and-source-a)

Comment: Although I agree the proposed duplicates can answer the question.  None of them directly answer the question of creating and restoring a system image on one set of hardware.  I'm sorry I couldn't infer the correct question while I was looking, so this question is valid for me, therefore could be for another user, but I leave that up to you.